# Múltiples versiones de funciones plantilla dependiendo de definición de macros

Tags: c++, template

Estoy haciendo una exportación de clases de C++ a python. En concreto, tengo que exportar instanciaciones de la clase [`Col` de la librería `Armadillo`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Col) (es algo parecido a un `std::vector< >`).

Esa librería tiene una particularidad. Las funciones de acceso a los elementos de una instancia de `Col< >` pueden configurarse para que realicen o no el chequeo de límites. **Pero** dicha configuración se realiza **mediante un [`#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#config_hpp_arma_no_debug)**. Es decir, se realiza **a nivel de archivo `.cpp`**.

Resulta que en mi código C++ **no me interesa** que se realice dicho chequeo. **Pero** en el código *exportado* a python **si**. Ello implica que habrá archivos `.cpp` en los que se defina dicha macro, y otros en los que no.

Como no *me fío* mucho de lo que pueda ocurrir en esta situación, he creado 4 pequeños archivos de prueba. Lo que yo me esperaba es que el enlazador *protestara* por múltiple definiciones, o algún error parecido:

> test.hpp

```
#ifndef TEST_HPP
#define TEST_HPP

#include <stdexcept>

template< typename T > T __attribute__ ((noinline)) dummy( const T &arg );

template< typename T > T __attribute__ ((noinline)) dummy( const T &arg ) {
#ifndef NDEBUG
  throw std::runtime_error( "" );
#endif

  return T( arg );
}

#endif
```

> debug.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp"

int debug( int arg ) {
  return dummy( arg );
}
```

> nodebug.cpp

```
#define NDEBUG

#include "test.hpp"

int nodebug( int arg ) {
  return dummy( arg );
}
```

> main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern int nodebug( int );
extern int debug( int );

int main( ) {
  int nd = nodebug( 10 );
  std::cout << "nodebug: " << nd << std::endl;
  int d = debug( 5 );
  std::cout << "debug: " << d << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Todo ello compilado con

> g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 nodebug.cpp debug.cpp main.cpp

Con todo lo anterior, la idea era forzar a que las funciones `debug( )` y `nodebug( )` fueran externas (y tuvieran que ser enlazadas), **y forzar lo mismo** para la plantilla `dummy< >( )`. De hecho, la orden

> nm -C main
> 0000000000001180 t int dummy<int>(int const&) [clone .isra.0]
> 0000000000001390 t int dummy<int>(int const&) [clone .isra.0]

muestra **2** entradas para `dummy< >( )` **con los mismos parámetros de plantilla**, cosa que no sabía que era posible.

Bueno, pues después de compilar y enlazar (cosa que me sorprendió que funcionara), ejecuto el `main` y obtengo:

> nodebug: 10
> terminate called after throwing an instance of `std::runtime_error`
> what():
> Abortado

Que, cosas de la vida, es un resultado *acorde* a mi código.

**¿ Como es esto posible ?** ¿ No debería de haberse producido un error de enlazado al existir múltiples definiciones **distintas** de mi función plantilla `dummy< >( )` con distinta implementación ? ¿ He cometido algún error en mi código de prueba y en realidad estoy haciendo algo distinto a lo que pretendo ? Y por último: Aunque estoy forzando la máxima compatibilidad al compilar (`-pedantic`), ¿ Este es un comportamiento estándar o estoy usando (sin saberlo y sin quererlo) alguna extensión del compilador ?

Comment: Tu programa viola la regla de una definición (One Definition Rule, ODR). No está permitido incluir dos definiciones diferentes de la misma función, tipo o plantilla. Si haces eso, el comportamiento es indefinido.

Comment: Eso es justamente lo que yo esperaba ... ¡ Pero funciona ! ¿¿¡¡ Porqué funciona !!?? No hay *warnings* ni errores ni nada :-O

Comment: Esta violación no requiere diagnóstico, el compilador no está obligado a emitir un error, ni warning. El comportamiento indefinido puede manifestarse de varias maneras, incluido el funcionamiento como se esperaba (siempre, o sólo en días pares).

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Si lo tienes claro, ponlo como respuesta :-) esperaré hasta mañana, pero, si no hay mas, lo acepto :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Este programa viola la [regla de una definición](https://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition). No está permitido incluir dos definiciones diferentes de la misma función, tipo o plantilla. Si haces eso, el comportamiento es indefinido.

Esta violación no requiere diagnóstico. El compilador no está obligado a emitir un error, ni warning.

[El comportamiento indefinido](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comportamiento_indefinido) puede manifestarse de varias maneras, incluido el funcionamiento como se esperaba (siempre, o sólo en días pares).