# ¿Por qué debería activar las advertencias de mi compilador?

Tags: c++, compilador

He visto que en algunas partes que han aconsejado que, un programador, debería activar las advertencias de su compilador.

No entiendo la razón de eso, si solo son advertencias; te advierten de algo, pero no es demasiado grave para impedir el funcionamiento del programa.

¿Por qué dicen que se debería de activar las advertencias de un compilador?

Además de eso, ¿Cómo podría habilitar las advertencias más importantes (No -Wall ni -Wextra, que ya las conozco)?

Comment: La respuesta de @Trauma lo cubre a la perfección. Solo quiero añadir una cosa. Viendo que eres un poco nuevo al lenguaje, me gustaría recomendarte que ademas de utilizar las advertencias del compilador, utilices un analizador estático. Por lo de `-Wall` supongo que usas clang, asi que prueba hecharle un vistaso a clang-tidy.

Comment: @Pablochaches No, no. No uso Clang, uso el compilador: TDM-GCC 4.7.1 64-bit Release; creo que GCC admite -Wall, aquí la página en que lo dice:[Advertencias GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) . No sé que es un Analizador Estático, pero investigaré a ver que es eso...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> te advierten de algo, pero no es demasiado grave para impedir el funcionamiento del programa.

Te equivocas **completamente** con eso.

La gran mayoría te avisarán sobre cosas que harán que tu programa **no funcione como esperas**, lo cual viene a ser mas o menos lo mismo que decirte, simplemente, que no va a funcionar.

Las advertencias vienen a ser como las normas de circulación: no es lo mismo el **no debes** que el **no puedes**.

> En una carretera limitada a 80Km, se te está indicando que **no debes** superar esa velocidad.
>
> Ahora bien, **físicamente hablando**, si tu vehículo tiene potencia suficiente, nada te impide superar ese límite.
>
> **Pero**, si superas el límite y te sancionan por ello ... luego no te quejes.

Podemos agrupas las advertencias en 2 grandes grupos:

- Advertencias sobre portabilidad, entendiendo como tal la obtención de resultados **idénticos** en distintas plataformas (combinaciones de hardware/software).
  Te advierten de que, tal vez, todo funcione en tu máquina actual ... pero **no tiene porqué** hacerlo en una máquina distinta.
- Advertencias sobre comportamientos peligrosos. Estas ya te dicen que puede que no funcione **ni en tu propia máquina**.

Aquí

```
int *meteduraDePata( ) {
  int variable = 10;

  return &variable;
}
```

> warning: address of local variable ‘variable’ returned

En ese ejemplo, el problema está claro. Devolver la dirección de una variable automática es un **comportamiento indefinido**. El espacio ocupado por dicha variable puede ser sobreescrito en cualquier momento.

Sin embargo, **físicamente hablando**, el código es correcto. Devolvemos ciertamente un puntero a un entero, luego la definición de la función (lo que se espera de ella) y su código interno (lo que realmente hace) es coincidente. Por lo tanto, desde el punto de vista de **conformancia con el lenguaje**, el código es correcto. De hecho, compila **sin errores** :-)

Comment: Oh, y yo pensaba que las advertencias no eran tan graves... Gracias :]

Comment: Agradece que el compilador los genere. Hay **errores graves** que [ni siquiera generan avisos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/372197/19610).

Comment: Sí, ahora estoy agradeciendo que el compilador genere los warnings. De hecho, tengo activado en -Werror para que el compilador me trate los warnings como errores. Pero, ¿Existe alguna forma de que el compilador me genere más warnings, pero que sean importantes?

Comment: Depende del compilador. En `gcc` y `clang`, el máximo de avisos es con `-Wall -Wextra`. **Todos son importantes**. De hecho, verás que cuando yo formulo preguntas, suelo indicar `compila sin errores ni avisos`. Es una referencia a calidad del código. Un código con avisos no sirve como ejemplo de nada hasta que desaparezcan.

Comment: Ok; ¡Así es! Un código con Warnings no sirve de ejemplo. Un error que cometía antes, era que, si me compilaba un código con Warnings, me daba igual. Pero ahora hago lo contrario.